# Why is my image appearing on the wrong window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to make a text-based game, but also want to incorporate images into it, I have a main menu, a window that is always open, and then a game window, that should have the image in, but for some reason, it appears in the menu window instead. Has anyone got any idea why?

```
def menu():

    master = Tk()
    master.geometry("350x300")
    master.wm_iconbitmap("zombie.ico")
    master.configure(background = '#484a2c')
    master.title("Menu")

    def game():  

        master = Tk()
        master.geometry("800x500")
        master.title("Game")
        master.wm_iconbitmap("zombie.ico")
        master.configure(background = '#484a2c')

        image = PhotoImage(file="Kitchenimage.gif")
        label5 = Label(image=image)
        label5.image = image
        label5.pack()

  label = Label(master, text = "Zombie Mansion", background = '#484a2c',  
  font = ("AR CHRISTY", 30))
  label.pack()

  b = Button(master,text = "Play Game", height = 1, width = 10)
  b.config(background = '#484a2c', activebackground = '#484a2c',  font = 
  ("AR CHRISTY", 14), command = get_username)
  b.place(x = 120, y = 70)


mainloop()
```

Comment: This code can't possibly create the label in another window because it only creates one window.

Comment: The code above isn't a [mcve]. You claim there are multiple windows but the code presents no evidence for that. Please try to improve the code you've provided.

Comment: I apologise, I have now changed it, I just thought it would be a bit long to put all up, it is still not full, but it shows the two windows I am referring about

Comment: @Katie Please try to fix your indentation. The code above should ideally be runnable with copy/paste-ing, try it yourself to see if it works please.

Comment: Also seems like what I _guessed_ appear to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why is my image appearing on the wrong window in Tkinter?"*

Assuming you have another instance of `Tk` as what you refer to as *main menu* somewhere in your code that you're not showing us like:

```
main = Tk()
```

in addition to `master = Tk()` in your `game` method, then it's because when you instantiate widgets without passing a parent widget explicitly like in:

```
label5 = Label(image=image)
```

then the widget's parent defaults to the `Tk` instance whose `mainloop` is being run, in above case supposedly `main`'s. By default widgets are shown under their parents, hence the reason.

Pass parent explicitly like:

```
label5 = Label(master=main, image=image)
```

or

```
label5 = Label(master, image=image)
```

---

In most cases, if not *all* cases, [**you shouldn't have multiple instances of `Tk`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045401/7032856). If you require additional windows, please use `Toplevel` widget.